# How to setup Huawei Vodafone 4G dongle on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, usb-modem, 4g

I tried creating a new mobile broadband connection but my device is not listed in the options. **lsusb** shows that it is recognized as a mass storage device. So i ejected the drive and reconnected it, it shows up as ethernet connection. Any suggestions?

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 12d1:1f16 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. K5150 LTE modem (Mass Storage Mode)
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04d9:fa51 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc.
```

Comment: If your device is not listed, you probably need to obtain the correct driver from the supplier or from Vodafone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it now shows up as Ethernet it's fine. That is how many new 3G/4G modems work.

Instead of configuring a new broadband connection, open the connection information for you new Ethernet connection, find th IP address and open it in the web browser. Follow instructions to connect/disconnect.

Comment: So, I opened the home page, it shows all the details of the modem. The status shows 'Disconnected'. But when I press the connect button, nothing happens. Are there any drivers that have to be installed?

Comment: Nothing to do with drivers. As long as you have access to that page, the OS has nothing else to do. It's all about your ISP now. You may need a PIN, activation, etc. but that's outside of the scope of AU.

Comment: Yup, had to enter the number and APN. Now it's connected. Thank you.